# Composable Attribute Updates in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I am working on an engineering simulation and am using this as an excuse to learn object oriented programming (being more familiar with procedural and functional programming). I am wondering how to update an object's attributes and then call a method on it in a way that could be used with, for example, a list comprehension. If I have a class `Foo` with an attribute `Foo.attrib`, I basically want to do this:

```py
myFoo = Foo(1)
attribValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
accumulator = []
for a in attribValues:
    myFoo.attrib = a
    accumulator.append(myFoo.someMethod) # depends on value of myFoo.attrib
```

Is there a more declarative way to do this, perhaps some way that I could make this pattern work with a `map` or list comprehension? This is a really common pattern in my code, so could this just be a design flaw?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A concrete example would make this easier to understand. You want to append an object method (without calling it?) into an accumulator... which is in your example completely unrelated to `myFoo.attrib`. Also, python is generally snake_case, not camelCase.

Comment: You should not use `map` or list-comprehensions for side-effects. Your attribute-assignment is a side effect. Just stick with this code. It is fine.

Comment: You could, of course, do something gastly like `[setattr(myFoo, 'attrib', a) or myFoo.some_method() for a in attrib_values]` but you *shouldn't*

Comment: @TemporalWolf: Yeah, I forgot some parens. `myFoo.someMethod` should have been `myFoo.someMethod()`. I wanted to provide a more concrete example, but I don't think anything from my library would have been helpful. On a side note, I have a hard time making my OO code referentially transparent. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Thanks. I completely agree on not putting side effects in `map`, since that kind of breaks what the function is intended to do. Honestly I would have preferred to not have side effects in generating the list, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: @BenDalFavero refactor your class to have a `replace` method that returns a *new copy* with the updated value. It's up to you, but that would be the naive solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using list comprehension:

```
accumulator = [myFoo.somemethod() for myFoo.attrib in attribValues]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that this could be done, and I'm glad I've seen it. However, I have to agree with the people above about using side effects in a list comp.